# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to read a json file using spark in Java. The few changes I tried were :

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Search").setMaster("local[*]");

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("../Users/pshah/Desktop/sample.json/*");

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
public class ParseData {

public static void main(String args[]){
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Search").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc= new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
    // Create the DataFrame
    DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("/Users/pshah/Desktop/sample.json");
    // Show the content of the DataFrame
    df.show();
}}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:198)
```

Comment: I've been unable to replicate your issue. Could You please provide pastebin with the JSON file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PT0g3jiM

Comment: Are you sure the path exists? it seems you point to the wrong path

Comment: Yes. The path exists. I just tried building the maven project again and it's running fine now. Thank you for the response!

Comment: The problem is the code runs fine for very simple JSON file. But when I am using nested json data . I get the following error : 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse a value for data type StructType() (current token: VALUE_STRING

Answer (score 0):

i wrote the same code, and meet the same problem. i put the people.json file under project directory src/main/resources. the reason is program could not finding the file. after i copy the people.json file to the program's working directory, the program works well